Permissions GitLab Kubernetes Agent
I need to define permissions for the gitlab kubernetes agent on GitLab 17.1
What I want to acheive is that from a CI-Pipeline the grp-1-project is deployed in OpenShift namespace ocp-1-project-1
What I need to avoid is that it is not possible to access the other OpenShift namespaces.
There is some kind of documentation
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/ci_cd_workflow.html
However it is not really understandable.
Is there anybody out there that has faced the same problem and can help me out of this?

